# mdTooltip not supports html in angular2-material

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

> mdTooltip  does not support html in angular2-material.

- Package used for angular material:

  *@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11*

*Markup:*

```html
<span  mdTooltip="<p>tooltip message</p>" mdTooltipPosition="above">
       <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</span>
```

Please suggest how to overcome this issues

Answer (score 0):

This [Github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5672) thread says that this won't be supported, although the styling can be controlled.

But if you want to give the user a rich experience in tooltips you can use popovers. Where you can put all the HTML content that you need. People have raised a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2691) for this as well. Till then you can use this package [ngx-popover](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-popover)

Comment: that i knew that material does not support html. i just wanted to know if any trick to overcome it. thanks for effort

Comment: @KetanAkbari Or you can just code an overlay yourself!

Comment: @Edric can you suggest and clue.